# Buefy b-table headers not recognizing CSS styles

Tags: buefy

I am trying to change the background-color of my b-table headers, but the style is not being recognized.

```
<style scoped>
.b-table .table th {
  background-color: #f3dcba !important;
} 
</style>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on possibility of fault?

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same issue, and the problem here is that you are trying to overwrite the style of a component that is not in the same scope as your Vue file.

One thing you can do, is to remove the `scoped` directive, and that would allow you to overwrite the style like so:

```
<style>
.b-table th { ... }
</style>
```

Be mindful that this might not be the best approach for this situation, and perhaps you should be creating a new `slot` for the table-headers, by creating some [Custom Headers](https://buefy.org/documentation/table#custom-headers). Once you've done this, you should be able to insert some specific class for the table-header in question, and even insert other custom behaviours.